# Algorithm: Filtering out a sequence of numbers in ascending order with least number of removed elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The actual problem context is very different but the generalized problem is trying to figure out an algorithm that filters a sequence of numbers in ascending order requiring least number of removed elements.

Applying the algorithm will look like the follwing.

```
wrong_sequence = [1,2,8,88,99,1,18,77,78,100,103]. # need to remove 88,99,1
correct_sequence = [1,2,8,18,77,78,100,103] # should NOT be [1,2,8,88,99]
enter code here
```

It is not as easy as just looping through the list and checking if the current number of the list is greater than the previous number because there could be a case where the current number is ascending yet should be filtered out.

For example, while 88,99 are ascending numbers, they should be removed from the list. In other words, [1,2,8,88,99] should NOT be the answer because removing 1, 18, 77, 78, 100, 103 numbers require removing more number of elements than removing 88,99,1

Any kind guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is the [longest increasing subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

Comment: Use of `least amount of work` to mean `least number of removed elements` is confusing.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you all for the help. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is the classic **LIS** problem - *longest increasing subsequence*. By finding the longest increasing subsequence you will also get the answer to your problem, and that is `n - l` where `n` is the length of the array and `l` is the length of the longest increasing subsequence.
[Here](https://cp-algorithms.com/sequences/longest_increasing_subsequence.html) is a more detailed post on this problem.
And also here is my take on this problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define NMAX int(1e5) //maximum size of array
#define INF int(1e9) // some large number
using namespace std;
int dp[NMAX],i,n,a[NMAX],max1,ans;
//max1 is the maximum length of the longest increasing subsequence
//dp[i] is the minimum value such that an increasing subsequence of length i ends in it
//because the values of dp[1],dp[2],dp[3],... are non-decreasing we can do a binary search
//to find our answer, thus getting a good time complexity -> O(nlog2n)
int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    dp[0]=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        dp[i]=INF;
        int st=0,dr=i-1,poz=0;
        while(st<=dr)
        {
            int m=(st+dr)/2;
            if(dp[m]<=a[i])
            {
                poz=m;
                st=m+1;
            }
            else dr=m-1;
        }
        dp[poz+1]=min(dp[poz+1],a[i]);
        max1=max(max1,poz+1);
    }
    ans=n-max1;
    cout<<ans<<" elements removed."<<endl;
    cout<<"The resulting array is: "<<endl;
    for(i=1;i<=max1;i++)
        cout<<dp[i]<<' ';
    return 0;
}
```